# The Missing Agent

Tags: steganography

My agent had been sent to investigate in London, but I hadn’t heard from him since. Today, I recieved this note:

> Hello! I found this amazing hotel with a very loud echo, and then I traveled to Lima to visit my Papa. I then traveled to India for a tango dance-off! They had great whiskey there, and I met a man named Alfa, and his wife Sierra! They were great at the Tango, and I got paired with Romeo (Alfa said that I danced like his papa would!)
>   Cheers!

What is he trying to say with this note?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Read the NATO phonetic alphabet letters in the message:
>  Hello! I found this amazing **hotel** with a very loud **echo**, and then I traveled to **Lima** to visit my **Papa**. I then traveled to **India** for a **tango** dance-off! They had great **whiskey** there, and I met a man named **Alfa**, and his wife **Sierra**! They were great at the **Tango**, and I got paired with **Romeo** (**Alfa** said that I danced like his **papa** would!) 
>  Cheers!
>  The letters spell **HELP IT WAS TRAP**.

Comment: Instantly saw it. Not surprised there was already an answer.

Comment: I spent half the time wrangling with Stack Exchange formatting lol